# Who is the king?

Tags: riddle, rhyme, poetry

High king on high throne 
lost his favorite son,
watched him fading for days 
'til he was finally gone.

Crestfallen and desperate,
a million tears he cried 
as he lamented his passing, 
and wore black all night.

Comment: Hi Lyra, and welcome to Puzzling :) Is this puzzle your own creation or did you find it somewhere else? Thanks.

Comment: Hey Stiv, thank you for you warm welcome!
I wrote it myself.

Comment: Great, thanks for letting us know :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the king here is:

> the **sky**.

*High king on high throne*
*lost his favorite son,*
*watched him fading for days*
*'til he was finally gone.*

> This describes the **waning of the moon**, as it 'fades' from a full moon to a new moon ('finally gone') over approximately 14 days. The 'high' king is the sky, up high; the 'favourite son' in question is the moon.

*Crestfallen and desperate,*
*a million tears he cried*

> The king's 'tears' are the stars, with millions of them shining upon his face.

*as he lamented his passing,*
*and wore black all night.*

> And in the absence of the moon, the night sky appears as if dressed in black mourning colours.

Comment: That is correct. Thank you for solving it!